# "ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4"

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am loading VGG19 model and  tring to apply 1d conv to decrease depth but I am getting the following error:
"ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4"

This is the function I am using:

```
def getModel():
    base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet')
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block4_conv4').output) 
    #model.output=(None, 28, 28, 512)   
    layer=keras.layers.Conv1D(96, (512), padding='same')
    model.summary()
    out=(layer)(model.output)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=out)
    model.summary()
    return model
```

Comment: You cannot apply `Conv1D` on the output of a `Conv2D` without unwrapping your `Conv2D` output on height and width axes. Maybe explain more clearly what you want to do.

Comment: What I really want is to decrease the depth of output from 512   to 96.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the last output is an output produced by a Conv2D layer which has the shape [batch size, height, width, channels]. This cannot be consumed by a `Conv1D`. `Conv1D` consumes [batch size, width, channels] inputs. In your case, since you're interested in cutting down the number of filters, all you need to do is convert your `Conv1D` to `Conv2D`.

Simply change your function to,

```
def getModel():
    base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet')
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block4_conv4').output) 

    # Here we are using Conv2D not Conv1D which gives 96 filters at the end.
    layer=keras.layers.Conv2D(96, (3,3), padding='same')
    model.summary()
    out=(layer)(model.output)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=out)
    model.summary()
    return model
```

Here,

- 96 - Is the number of filters
- (3,3) - Is the kernel height and width of the convolution layer.